# Retrieve information from SoundCloud developer console

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to download the information about this user : https://soundcloud.com/beeldengeluid/, 
and about this group : https://soundcloud.com/groups/het-geluid-van-nederland through your developer console here : http://developers.soundcloud.com/console. The user - "Beeld en Geluid"  has 2,230 records, but all my attempts to download the information ended with just 50 records. Are there any user specific constraints or some user key that I should use to retrieve all the information in .xml format from the developer console?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no 'constraints' or 'some user key' for that. but you can use pagination:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#pagination

Answer (score 0):

Every call is limited by 50 results. Use the offset parameter in the querystring to get the next 50 results and so on:

example... "...&offset=0&..."
Next 50 results would be retrieved by using "...&offset=50&..."

Put this in a loop in your code to get the complete list.